# Want to Print Partial string in GDB

Tags: gdb

I am writing a GDB macro to analyze the core and print a string. The output of string from core is "sp-4/0/2". Now I need to print only "sp", excluding others. I am not sure how to achieve this in GDB. Any pointers of this would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See, argv[1] is "sp-4/0/2"

```
(gdb) p argv[1]
$4 = 0x7fffffffe3fa "sp-4/0/2"
```

And this is only two first chars:

```
(gdb) printf "%.2s\n", argv[1]
sp
```

Or

```
(gdb) printf "%c%c\n", argv[1][0],argv[1][1]
sp
```

Answer (score 0):

The following alternative works even when the size isn't known statically:

```
(gdb) p {char} argv[1]@2
```

I.e. you can replace the `2` by a variable or register value. This is useful when you are adding a breakpoint in e.g. `write` and don't have debug symbols available:

```
(gdb) b -qualified write # only match write, don't do globbing
(gdb) cond 1 $rdi == 2 # only when writing to stderr
(gdb) command 1
bt
p {char} $rsi@$rdx # print (partial) buffer
cont
```

The above works when the System V AMD64 calling convention is used, but can be easily adopted to the arm calling conventions by adapting the registers.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting print length can be explicitly set in GDB.  That way, the output is limited, but truncation is also displayed.

```
(gdb) p argv[1]
$1 = 0x7fffffffe410 "sp-4/0/2"
(gdb) show print elements
Limit on string chars or array elements to print is 10000.
(gdb) set print element 2
(gdb) p argv[1]
$2 = 0x7fffffffe410 "sp"...
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**